# Traversing binomial tree breadth first

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I am trying to traverse what I believe is called a binomial tree. However, there is a problem with traversing the bottom left node.

This is a representation of the data structure
[image]

This is the code. I feel it is pretty close to a solution but not quite -- there is something missing and it might be something minor. When the bottom left node is to be traversed, the binomial function has low == high, so it doesn't traverse it.

```
       private State? BFS()
    {
        State state = new State();
        foo(0,items.Count,state);
        return bestState;
    }

    private void foo(int low, int high, State state)
    {
        int lCount = low;

        while (lCount < high)
        {
            State newState = new State(items[lCount++], state);
            if (predicate(newState))
            {
                bestState = newState;
            }
            queue.Enqueue(newState);
        }
        while(low<high)
        {

            foo(++low, high, queue.Dequeue());

        }

    }
```

Comment: There is something missing ... and it's the rest of the code. See [mcve].

Comment: It looks like the tree is the right shape, but it's not BFS.